# Mixed-effects: length of the experiment as a continuous fixed effect?

Tags: r, lme4-nlme

I have measurement of nitrogen uptake `Nup` across 4 different `SITE` very far from each other and in different years (e.g. 1998-2004, 1993-1999, 2001-2004,…), hence independent measurements. I have two treatments at each site, elevated levels of `CO2` and ambient CO2 concentration, and I want to know whether Nup is higher at elevated CO2 compared to ambient within each site. The `CO2` treatments are nested as `BLOCK/RING`. My model is therefore as follows:

```
m1 <-lmer(logNup ~ CO2*SITE + (1|BLOCK/RING),data=df)
```

Since I have yearly measurement, my question is whether or not I should include the length of the experiment `(TRTYEAR)` as a fixed effect, in which case the model could be:

```
m2 <-lmer(logNup ~ CO2*SITE*TRTYEAR + (1|BLOCK/RING),data=df)
```

And furthermore, in case I have to include `TRTYEAR` as as fixed effect, I do not know whether TRTYEAR should be numerical or factor.

Please, I would appreciate any help in regards of whether or not include `TRTYEAR` and its format (factor or numerical).
Thanks

Comment: Is your dependent uptake per year or cumulated uptake?

Comment: One measurement per year

Comment: So, including `TRTYEAR` would model a linear temporal trend in your measurements? (If you include it, it should probably be numeric.)

Comment: The problem is that when I include it TRTYEAR as a numeric fixed effect as in m2, the post-hoc analysis makes no sense at all, with significant CO2 treatment effect at sites that clearly can’t have significant effects, and not significant effect in a site which visually should be clearly significant. And in any case I am not interested in the trend. Should I just leave TRTYEAR out of the model?

Comment: Yow many years do you observe? If the number is small then you should rather use factor.

Comment: In one of the sites I have 11 years of observations, whereas there are two sites with only 2-3 years of observations

Comment: Please, help me